# Can I initialize arrays at runtime?

Tags: python

I have an array of unknown length `a = [a1, a2, ... an]` passed by user in main function, ie `a = [3,3,4,1]` or `a = [1,1,13,4,5]`.

In my program how do I create arrays out of these variables since I don't know the length of array `a`?

For example let's say user passed `a = [3,3,4,1]`, I need to create 4 arrays, `a1` with 3 elements, `a2` with 3 elements, `a3` with 4 elements, `a4` with 1 element.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are the elements you want in these new arrays ?

Comment: so the elements from the array given by the user are the number of nodes in a neural network per layer..I am trying to get those.

Comment: The answer is that you don't worry about memory allocation here; python does it for you and you're pretty powerless to change that

Comment: Please give examples of `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`.

Comment: a1 would be an array of 3 elements with 3 nodes I can add weights to later and process. a2 would be an array of 3 elements with 3 nodes I can add weights to later and process. a3 would be an array of 4 elements with 4 nodes I can add weights to later and process. a4 would be an array of 1 elements with 1 node I can add weights to later and process

Comment: You seem to be new to interpreted languages... this is Python's bread and butter.

First of all, arrays in Python are called Lists.

Secondly, you don't need to declare the lengths of lists, they are ultimately linked lists under the covers, but they give you array-like semantics.

Most likely, you don't need to do what you are trying to do... try asking again with what you plan to do with these lists.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Like, i see your intention with the comment about neural network style initialization, but the point remains, if you're working with python, you aren't controlling memory allocation or reserving places for arrays. You don't need to do *any* of this.

Comment: call it a case of you starting with a wrong premise.

Comment: If you don't know the number of arrays up-front, how do you know whether any ``aN`` actually exists? If you don't know whether any ``aN`` actually exists, how do you expect *other* code to work with it? Why not use a nested "array" (``list``) so that e.g. ``len(aN[3]) == a[3]``?

Comment: @Cargo23 None of the common Python implementations use linked lists for ``list``. Commonly, ``list`` uses a dynamically allocated array for content, over-allocated to avoid re-allocation on every append, plus a header to store length and other metadata.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh A new solution is proposed which I presume a clean approach to deal this specific requirement. Hope you you agree with this

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all the elements of an array (list) with `for ... in`:

```
for var in a:
    # do something with var
```

Lists don't need to be pre-allocated (they will dynamically resize as you add things to them), but if you do want to create an list of a certain length, an easy way is the multiplication operator:

```
a1 = [0] * 3  # creates [0, 0, 0]
```

Note that if you have a dynamic number of values (whether the values are lists or something else), you probably don't want static variable names like `a1`, `a2`, etc.  Instead you probably want a list of lists:

```
arrays = []  # empty list
for var in a:
    arrays.append([0] * var)  # adds a list of length var to arrays
```

If you started with `a = [3, 3, 4, 1]` then `arrays` will now be:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
```

Comment: They never asked how to iterate over the list. This is not the first time we've had this kind of discussion; you haven't answered the question because the question doesn't even exist

Comment: Doing something based on the contents of an array will necessarily involve iterating over it, and I was able to infer from the statement "since I don't know the length of `a`" that they didn't know how to do that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create an array from a like this:

```
array = [i * [None] for i in a]
```

a1 would then be the first element in the array, a2 the second etc.

```
a1 = array[0]
a2 = array[1]
```

Comment: To what end? I don't get what this addresses from the question